# How to sudo su over PuTTY's psftp.exe

Tags: linux, sftp, putty, sudo, su

With (PuTTY) `PSFTP.exe` it is possible to open open a shell script to perform certain actions on Linux.

In this example I am using `psftp.exe` to open `get30.txt` file.

```
%%PROJECT/ROOT_DIRECTORY%%\PuTTY\psftp.exe user@domain.nl -pw password -b "%%PROJECT/ROOT_DIRECTORY%%\Scripts\%%ENVIRONMENT/NAME%%\get30.txt"
```

In the `get30.txt` I have the following actions:

```
sudo su -l4097gps
cd /appl/gps/RIT/IN/30/RAP-T1
chmod 777 GP*.*
get -r /appl/gps/RIT/IN/30/RAP-T1
rm /appl/gps/RIT/IN/30/RAP-T1/*
quit
```

Unfortunately `psftp` does not recognise `sudo su`.

How can I `sudo` to a different user after I have logged on with my own user?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible. Those commands you're sending aren't arbitrary shell commands - they're SFTP commands. They happen to look like shell commands (rm, cd, etc), but they're just mirroring the shell equivalents. There is no 'sudo' command in most SFTP implementations, thus, you can't do it.

The only case where I'm wrong is if you're using a custom SFTP server and client that supports 'su', such as the one offered by Van Dyke software. However, you'd be using 'su' there, and be required to authenticate, instead of using 'sudo'.

Additionally, see this post on the serverfault stackoverflow:

[How to change user for more rights on a sftp client](https://serverfault.com/questions/336540/how-to-change-user-for-more-rights-on-a-sftp-client)

Comment: Just to add, it sounds like OP may be getting `SSH` and `SFTP` confused, which is very reasonable since `SFTP` is rolled all up with `SSH`, but it's an entirely different protocol. I completely agree with the edit to seek elevating the SFTP user's rights for the file or directory that they are trying to SFTP files from.

Answer (score 3):

The `sudo` is a shell command, not an SFTP command.

There's no `sudo` or equivalent in the SFTP protocol in general nor in `psftp` commands.

Though if you are connecting to an OpenSSH server, you can instruct it to run the SFTP subsystem/server with elevated privileges using a command like:

```
sudo /bin/sftp-server
```

Unfortunately the `psftp` does not allow you to change the command used to launch the SFTP server.

You can use WinSCP instead:

```
open sftp://user:password@domain.nl/ -rawsettings SftpServer="sudo /bin/sftp-server"
```

But there's lot of limitations to allow this working. Particularly the `sudo` may not require password. For details, see WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

See also the guide to [converting PuTTY PSFTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: the best answer what I see :)  but... is it possible to add support for sudo password in WinSCP ?

Comment: @Znik A full support is not possible due to conflicts with the SFTP protocol. But with some limitations (if the `sudo` is configured not to require TTY), it may work. You can vote for this feature at https://winscp.net/tracker/1247